# Load JSON from assets and add it to JSONObject: Android

Tags: java, android, json

I need to store the user input and other string to a local storing method to use it later. Also I need to update it with data every time the user inputs other preferences and read it. I've chosen JSON for this task, hope it's the best option.

My problem is that every time I close the app (or update the app version) the file gets reset.

I would save the `JSONObject` to the internal storage and update, change, read and check for its existence every time the app starts.

This file is the core of my app as it stores the preferences.

**UPDATE:**
I've used SharedPreferences to do my task:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: If all the file is doing is saving preferences, why can't you use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)? It's designed to take away a lot of the hassle of loading and saving simple data.

Comment: Will the data be there even after the app is updated to another version?

Comment: Yes. SharedPreferences are persistent and only removed when the app is fully uninstalled.

Comment: Use a `SharedPreference` it's way easier. It's highly recommended that you use `Gson` : https://github.com/google/gson to manage changes in your `JsonObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've switched to using SharedPreferences. Thanks for your recommendations.

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: Ok. I'll delete it then, but how should I say that my problem is fixed.

Comment: I was talking about the answer, not the post.

Comment: me too. 
No need to delete the answer, you can make your answer more clear(What you did / what helped you to solve the issue, Might help some other in future)